# Return additional attributes after FreeRADIUS authentication

Tags: freeradius

I would like to return additional attributes in the response after successfully authenticating against radius.

Consider the following:

```
testuser    Cleartext-Password := "testpassword"

DEFAULT
 Unix-FTP-Shell = "Test"
```

In sites-enabled/default...

```
post-auth {

update reply {
        Unix-FTP-Shell := "%{Unix-FTP-Shell}"
    }
```

When I do `radtest testuser testpassword localhost 10 testing123`  I get:

```
Sent Access-Request Id 231 from 0.0.0.0:20227 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
        User-Name = "testuser"
        User-Password = "testpassword"
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.16.200.3
        NAS-Port = 10
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00
        Cleartext-Password = "testpassword"
Received Access-Accept Id 231 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 0.0.0.0:0 length 20
```

Answer (score 1):

from the manpage of [unlang](https://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/unlang.html), Attributes can be referenced with the following syntax:

```
&Attribute-Name
&Attribute-Name:TAG
&Attribute-Name[NUM]
&<list>:Attribute-Name
&<list>:Attribute-Name:TAG[NUM]
```

you may try using:

```
update reply {
   &Unix-FTP-Shell = "%{Unix-FTP-Shell}"
}
```

If it doesn't work, you may want to run the debugging mode by stopping the service and running `freeradius -X | tee /tmp/radiusdebug.log` on the foreground to get all the detail possible.

Hope it helps.